# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular

Hi im new in Angular and i have an error like this

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

from this line of codes

```
function defaultErrorLogger(console, ...values) {
((/** @type {?} */ (console.error)))(...values); }
```

its a auto generated code from angular and i didnt do anything about that. please help
thank you so much

Comment: You should post this issue to angular GitHub issues as it is related to there internal code.

Comment: when are you getting this error? WHich command are you running ? More details should be provided

Comment: Do you do `toLowerCase` somewhere in your code? That's where the problem actually is

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a property whose value you didn't set, that's making it return undefined.

You can send the full message on your console or take an image of it.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer